# Proof that equation $Lf=u$ guarantees satisfiability of weak form $\langle Lf,v \rangle = \langle u ,v \rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-element-method

## Problem

Let's observe in a closed interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ real-valued and continuous vectorspace $\mathcal{F}([a,b],\mathbb{R})$. Where $\langle ., .\rangle$ is some scalar product. This scalar product only satisfies axioms when $\overline{v},\overline{w},\overline{u} \in V$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ (V is space for scalar product)

1. $\langle \overline{v}, \overline{w} \rangle = \langle \overline{w}, \overline{v} \rangle$
2. $\langle \overline{v}, \overline{w} + \overline{u} \rangle = \langle \overline{v}, \overline{w} \rangle + \langle \overline{v}, \overline{u} \rangle$
3. $\langle c \overline{v}, \overline{w} \rangle = c \langle \overline{v}, \overline{w} \rangle $
4. $\langle \overline{v}, \overline{v} \rangle \ge 0$; and $\langle \overline{v},\overline{v}\rangle = 0$ if and only if $\overline{v}= \overline{0}$

Now let's observe equation

$$ Lf = u, $$

where $L$ is linear transformation in space $\mathcal{F}$ and $f,u \in \mathcal{F}$. Then weak form of this equation is

$$ \langle Lf, v \rangle = \langle u , v \rangle \quad \forall v \in \mathcal{F} $$

Proof that the equation $Lf=u$ guarantees satisfiability of $\langle Lf,v \rangle = \langle u , v \rangle$.

---

Could someone give an explanation/hint on how should I approach this? To put in other words, I am completely lost with this. I tried to take a scalar product with $v$ from both sides of the equation which leads to the equation with the scalar product. Then your somehow suppose to show that the equation is true $\forall v \in \mathcal{F}$ but not quite sure how to do this? After all, I'm not even sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: Huh? There's nothing to prove here! If $x=y$ then $<x,z>=<y,z>$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich This is what I was thinking but I was quite unsure this I thought "This cannot be so easy"

Comment: Possibly it is in fact a trivial problem. Possibly you didn't state it here quite correctly.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I tried to state it 1:1 with just translation in between. The original language that this problem is stated is not English.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich can you notice anything that could be "lost in translation"? Something that could make this into an actual problem?